Puppeteer page.$$
So i'm currently trying to get some info from twitter using puppeteer and i got to the example page needed.
The thing is, when i run this query at console in my browser the results appear:
$x(`//div[@data-testid="tweetText"]`)

even if i want to extract the specific text from it works:
$x(`//div[@data-testid="tweetText"]`)[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].wholeText

However when writing the code i'm trying to use page.$$ to get all elements that match the (already tested) selector:
const [tweetData] = await page.$$(`xpath/.//div[@data-testid='tweetText']`);

Does anyone knows how to get this done? If possible bringing the specific text would be great!
Thanks in advance!
I tried:
const [tweetData] = await page.$$(`xpath/.//div[@data-testid='tweetText']`);

and got nothing in return instead of all elements that matched my selector, tested and working on chrome console.

You should use page.$x

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

page.$$ doesn't wait for anything. Twitter is a single page app so everything loads asynchronously. You'll want to wait for elements to appear before you can work with them. Also, it may have iframes, shadow roots or detect and block your bot. Please describe your actual goal with your scrape or automation, and share a [mcve] of your code (complete and runnable). Also, avoid xpath. There's virtually no need for it in scraping. Thanks.
